# When do projective modules give generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I am reading [arXiv:math/0111066 [math.RA]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111066.pdf) and am stuck understanding the proof of Lemma 1.4.  The only part I don't follow is the claim:

> If $B$ is a [projective (right) module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module) over a ring $R$ which is [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring), then $B$ is a generator for $\operatorname{Mod}-R$.

I don't see how to leverage the hypothesis that $R$ is simple.  $B$ is the direct summand of a free module (and free modules generate) but why does that show that $B$ generates (and not the complement of $B$?)

**Update:** One possible reference is [Lang's Algebra](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&q=rieffel#v=snippet&q=rieffel&f=false) section XVII, 7.  Note that $B$ becomes a left $R'(B)=\operatorname{End}_R(B)$ module in a natural way.  Morita's Theorem says that $B$ is a generator if and only if the natural map $R\rightarrow \operatorname{End}_{R'}(B)$ is onto ($B$ is "balanced") and $B$ is finitely generated projective over $R'(B)$.  However, I have no idea how to verify this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know how to prove this if $B$ is finitely generated; fortunately in Lemma 1.4 this follows because $B$ is a direct summand (hence a quotient) of $P$ which is assumed to be finitely generated.

Given that, $B$ is a direct summand of some finite free module $R^n$, hence can be presented as the image of an idempotent $e \in M_n(R)$. In [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/generators/) (skip down to "More explicit Morita equivalences") you can see a proof of the following (this should be standard but I don't know a reference and it was faster to just prove it):

> **Lemma:** $\text{im}(e)$ is a generator iff $e \not \equiv 0 \bmod I$ for any proper two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$.

If $R$ is simple the only such ideal is $I = (0)$ so this condition is automatically satisfied for any nonzero idempotent $e$ and hence for any nonzero finitely generated projective module $B$.

(The blog post is mostly a discussion about different definitions of "generator," which are inequivalent in general but which basically all agree in $\text{Mod}(R)$ and more generally in any cocomplete abelian category. These equivalences allow me to use the weakest definition of generator, which is an object $B$ such that if $C$ is any nonzero object then there's a nonzero map $B \to C$.)

Comment: I don't quite follow to use of Morita equivalence in your blog post.  Haven't you shown that $P = \text{im}(e) \subseteq R^n$ is a "weak generator" of the category of $M_n(R)$ modules, if and only if $e$ is a full idempotent? But we want to consider $P$ in the category of $R$ modules, and I don't see how to get this from Morita equivalence.  That said, I do seem to have brute-force calculation which shows the result is true.  Am I missing a trick?

Comment: @Mathew: hmm you're right, I don't know what I was thinking, I don't think that argument works at all. If I transport $P$ across the Morita equivalence to $M_n(R)$-modules I get $P^n$, not $P$. Let's see if I can fix this... (the statement about full idempotents you can find in other sources so that one, at least, I still believe.)

Comment: @Matthew: okay, the argument can just be done without the Morita equivalence at all (I'll edit this into the post). If $e \in M_n(R)$ is an idempotent with $\text{im}(e) = P$ then a morphism $P \to M$ is an $n$-tuple $(m_1, \dots m_n) \in M^n$ such that $e(m_1, \dots m_n) = (m_1, \dots m_n)$, and a nonzero such tuple exists iff $e$ acts by a nonzero idempotent. If $M$ is nonzero the action of $M_n(R)$ on $M^n$ factors through some proper two-sided ideal which must be $M_n(I)$ for some proper two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$ so the condition is, again, that $e \not \equiv 0 \bmod I$ for any such $I$.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is easy to see that $R$ itsef is a generator.
2. I will provide you with an epimorphism $P \twoheadrightarrow R$, notice that this is the same of providing you with a non-zero map, because $R$ is simple. Such a "cover" of a generator shows that also $P$ is a generator.
3. Being projective, $P$ is a split submodule of $R^{(\Gamma)}$, the free module generated by some set $\Gamma$. Now, consider all the projections $\pi_i: R^{(\Gamma)} \to R$, composing with the inclusion $P \hookrightarrow R^{(\Gamma)} \to R$, there must be at least one $i$ such that the projection is non-zero, because $P$ is a nontrivial module.

Comment: Why does $R$ simple mean that it's enough to get a non-zero homomorphism $P\rightarrow R$?  I mean (and obviously the paper I am referring to means) that $R$ is simple as a ring.  There is some debate about what this means: I _think_ the paper means in the least restrictive sense: $R$ has no (nontrivial, two-sided) ideals.

Comment: @MatthewDaws.  This is a very good point, I did not think about it. I don't know how to fix the issue, but I can't image a proof which is not in this spirit.